# If you are married filing jointly, is your AGI (or modified AGI) the sum total of your income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira

I'm trying to determine whether my wife can contribute to an IRA.  The [table on the IRS website talks about AGI](http://www.irs.gov/retirement/participant/article/0,,id=202517,00.html) and I'd just like to know whether the AGI in the case of married filing jointly is our combined income or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It includes income for both spouses, as it is calculated from a version of your tax return (which includes both your incomes), as shown in [this IRS description](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch17.html#en_US_2010_publink1000172667).  There is [a discussion here](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch17.html#en_US_2010_publink1000172644) about limit on a traditional IRA deduction if a spouse is covered by a retirement plan.